# How to refresh the web page after it is changed one time?

Tags: javascript, refresh, html

```js
 

function change(){
    item = document.getElementById("first");
    item.value = "second";
    item.id = "second";
}

ob = document.getElementById("first");
ob.addEventListener("click",change);
```

```html
 
<input id="first" type="button" value="first">
```

When you click the input, it turned into:

```
<input id="second" type="button" value="second">
```

My requirement is to write javascript code so that when you click the input whose id is `second`, the web page will refresh. That is to say, to change the current input element:

```
<input id="second" type="button" value="second">
```

into the previous:

```
<input id="first" type="button" value="first">
```

Here is my try:

```js
 

function change(){
    item = document.getElementById("first");
    item.value = "second";
    item.id = "second";
}

ob = document.getElementById("first");
ob.addEventListener("click",change); 

function previous(){
    document.execCommand('Refresh') 
}

ob = document.getElementById("second");
ob.addEventListener("click",previous);
```

```html
   <input id="first" type="button" value="first">
```

```
error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
at  line27.
```

Comment: We do not have the command `"Refresh"`. See the **[list of commands of `document.execCommand` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)**. I think you wand use **[``Location reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)** function instead?

Answer (score 14):

Can't actually understand, why would you need such an obscure way to do this and what does `.execCommand("Refresh")` even supposed to mean - `execCommand` documentation doesn't even list `refresh` as an option, however, your errors are caused by these lines:

```
item = document.getElementById("first");

ob = document.getElementById("second");
```

In the first case, when you try to change the item's `val` and `id` the second time - it already has another `id` (changed by the first function use)

In the second case you try to bind an event listener to the element which is absent on the page at the moment of that line execution.

If I were you, I would've written smth like this (assuming that for some reason you really need to change the object's id):

```js
ob = document.getElementById('first');

ob.addEventListener('click',function(){
  if (this.id=='first') {
    this.id = 'second';
    this.value = 'second';
  } else {
    location.reload();
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="first" type="button" value="first">
```

Answer (score 7):

So, I'm not entirely clear on why you're going about this as noted (another example may help), but you can get rid of the error and implement your functionality with the below code:

```js
function change(){
  var item = document.getElementById("first");
  item.value = "second";
  item.id = "second";
  item.removeEventListener("click", change);
  item.addEventListener("click", refresh);
}

function refresh(){
  document.location.reload();
}

var ob = document.getElementById("first");
ob.addEventListener("click",change);
```

```html
<input id="first" type="button" value="first">
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem with your code, as far as I can tell, is that you're getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "addEventListener" of null

And it is on this line:

```
ob.addEventListener("click", previous);
```

This is because the line above, `ob` is redefined to be this:

```
ob = document.getElementById("second");
```

Because an element with `id="second"` is only created in the function `change()`, this line is causing errors because it is actually executed before `change()` is run, meaning that your code stops as soon as it runs.

In short, you should place these two lines:

```
var ob = document.getElementById("second");
ob.addEventListener("click", previous);
```

Inside the `change()` function, so your code should look like so:

```js
ob = document.getElementById("first");
ob.addEventListener("click", change);

function change() {
  item = document.getElementById("first");
  item.value = "second";
  item.id = "second";
  ob = document.getElementById("second");
  ob.addEventListener("click", previous);
}

function previous() {
  document.execCommand('Refresh')
}
```

```html
<input id="first" type="button" value="first">
```

And the other thing you should do is use `location.reload()` for reloading the page:

```js
ob = document.getElementById("first");
ob.addEventListener("click", change);

function change() {
    item = document.getElementById("first");
    item.value = "second";
    item.id = "second";
    ob = document.getElementById("second");
    ob.addEventListener("click", previous);
}

function previous() {
    location.reload();
}
```

```html
<input id="first" type="button" value="first">
```

---

However, if you just wanted to make this:

```
<input id="second" type="button" value="second">
```

Into this:

```
<input id="first" type="button" value="first">
```

Inside your `previous()` function, then all you have to do is make your `previous()` function look like this:

```
function previous() {
    item = document.getElementById("second");
    item.value = "first";
    item.id = "first";
    ob = document.getElementById("first");
    ob.addEventListener("click", change);
}
```

(I have structured `previous()` pretty much the same as `change()` to make it easier for your debugging purposes)

After all of your code has been modified and improved, the final, working snippet looks like this:

```js
var ob = document.getElementById("first");
ob.addEventListener("click", change);

function change() {
    item = document.getElementById("first");
    item.value = "second";
    item.id = "second";
    ob = document.getElementById("second");
    ob.addEventListener("click", previous);
}

function previous() {
    item = document.getElementById("second");
    item.value = "first";
    item.id = "first";
    ob = document.getElementById("first");
    ob.addEventListener("click", change);
}
```

```html
<input id="first" type="button" value="first">
```

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var item = document.getElementById("first");
  function change(){
      item.value = "second";
      item.id = "second";
      var second = document.getElementById("second");
   second.addEventListener("click",previous); 
  }
  item.addEventListener("click",change); 
  
  function previous(){
      console.log(1);
      //document.execCommand('Refresh');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First solution:

```js
var element_1 = document.getElementById("first"),
    element_2 = document.getElementById("second");

element_1.addEventListener("click", function(){
    element_1.style.display = "none";
    element_2.style.display = "";
});
element_2.addEventListener("click", function(){
    element_2.style.display = "none";
    element_1.style.display = "";
});
```

```html
<input id="first" type="button" value="first">
<input id="second" type="button" value="second" style="display: none;">
```

Second solution if you want just one button:

```js
var current_id = "first";

function changeBtn() {
    document.getElementById(current_id).removeEventListener("click", changeBtn);
    document.getElementById(current_id).value = current_id === "first" ? "second" : "first";
    document.getElementById(current_id).id = current_id === "first" ? "second" : "first";
    current_id = current_id === "first" ? "second" : "first";
    addClickEvent();
}

function addClickEvent() {
    document.getElementById(current_id).addEventListener("click", changeBtn);
}

addClickEvent();
```

```html
<input id="first" type="button" value="first">
```

Comment: It's definitely not an dom load issue, the error is because of the non existence of an element.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function change() {
    item = document.getElementById("first");
    item.value = "second";
    item.id = "second";
    if(item.id == "second"){
        location.reload();  // only reload if changed
    }
}

ob = document.getElementById("first");
ob.addEventListener("click", change);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register a listener on the document object and filter out any other clicks but the desired ones. You then avoid any listener adding/removing and the whole logic can be in one place within one scope.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const options = ['first', 'second']
  const t = e.target
  if (!~options.indexOf(t.id)) return

  const selected = options[Number(t.id === options[0])] // truthy value (t.id === 'first') is converted to 1 which selects the 'second' item, falsy does the opposite
  
  t.id = selected
  t.value = selected
  // do another stuff
})
```

```html
<input type="button" id="first" value="first">
```